# string indices must be integers aws lambda api

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    "idsA=event['items'][0]['ids']"
```

When i want call with Python the JSON object items which contains arrays ids.. in aws lambda, from API,
It returns this error:

```
"string indices must be integers"`
```

I think the problem can be in COnfigure test event :

```
{
  "ids": "ids",
  "contents": "contents",
  "ResultID": "ResultID",
  "QueryID": "QueryID",
   "nR": "nR",
   "items": "ids"     


}
```

or in API getaaway in JSON body mapping template:

```
{
    "items": [
    #foreach($elem in $input.params('items').split(','))
        {
            "ids": "$elem.ids",
            "contents": "$elem.contents"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
    ],
    "QueryID": "$input.params('QueryID')",
    "nR": "$input.params('nR')"
}
```

Comment: Assuming the first dictionary in your post is called `event` then `event['items'][0]` returns the first letter of the value of the key `items` which is a string that you are attempting to slice using another `string`. If I have misunderstood please post what `event` looks like.

Comment: check my update

Comment: Sorry that still didn't help me understand. As I mentioned before the problem is that you're indexing a string with another string. It must mean that `event['items'][0]` is a string and not a dict as you assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like in your test event items is supposed to be a JSON array of objects:

```
{
    "ResultID": "ResultID",
     "QueryID": "QueryID",
     "nR": "nR",
     "items": [
         {
             "ids": [1, 2, 3],
              "contents": ["content1", "content2"]
         }
    ]
}
```

... but I think there may be a template mapping issue here as well. What does a raw request to API gateway look like?

Comment: Thanks! it seems it works, but the output format of 1d int array is strange:

Comment: [  "1",   ",",  "2",  ",",  "3"]

Comment: ids is just a string in this JSON and you're accessing it as as array. Did you want it to be an array in the JSON?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your desired test event structure.